# Scheduling Non - CPU resources

Tags: resources, cpu, scheduling, resource-scheduling

I have to write an essay on scheduling non-CPU resources. I can't find any information on what exactly this entails, could anybody give me an idea as to what this is.

Comment: This sounds like homework or some variation of homework. It also isn't specified as a programming problem. You might have have better luck researching scheduling algorithms on http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=scheduling or http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=scheduling

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it asks about the field of scheduling generally, which is better answered by computer science or operations research.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually anything that you can plan, for example train scheduling on the station (movement between tracks, arrivals, departures, etc) This particular example is actually a topic for roadef competition this year, you can read about it [here](http://challenge.roadef.org/2014/en/sujet.php)
Transportation is actually often solved real-life scheduling problem that a lot of companies are facing.